# need batch file variable to store result of running a command (escaping issue?)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I think this is an escaping issue but I'm not certain because I've tried every combination of escaping I can think of and none of them work.

This Git command returns a commit hash that I need to store in a batch file variable...

```
git show --grep="MySearchString" --pretty=format:"%H" --no-patch
```

This batch file command works...

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git show --grep="MySearchString" --no-patch') do @set foobar=%%a
echo %foobar%
```

But when I add in the `--pretty=format:"%H"` part the batch file fails...

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git show --grep="MySearchString" --pretty=format:"%H" --no-patch') do @set foobar=%%a
echo %foobar%
```

I've tried escaping the `--pretty=format:"%H"` part using \ and ^ but can't get it run. Where am I going wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: If `%H` is a format for the `git` command then the percent symbol needs to be escaped by doubling the percent symbol.

Comment: @Squashman doubling it like you say works, is does echo out the correct value, but it also spits this out right before it: `fatal: Invalid object name 'format'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double the percent-sign (it's special char in batch, this evaluates to single percent-sign) and escape equals with caret `^`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git show --grep^="MySearchString" --pretty^=format:"%%H" --no-patch') do @set foobar=%%a
echo %foobar%
```

or without the quotes around %H works too:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('git show --grep^="MySearchString" --pretty^=format:%%H --no-patch') do @set foobar=%%a
echo %foobar%
```

Commands fed to 'for' need complicated and cumbersome escaping; I find that directing the results to a file and then parsing the file is a more straightforward strategy.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried it without the quotes?

... --pretty-format:%H?